# Disappearing Relationship in Power BI Desktop

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi

I am getting data from VSTS (currently, Azure DevOps) via their web API. I have a couple of tables that have a one-to-many relationship.  Sometimes, when I refresh the data, the relationship disappears.  There is no error, no message of any sort.  If I recreate the relationship, all is well.  My guess is that there is something wrong with the data, but with zero information, I have no real starting point.

Any ideas of where to look?

Answer (score 0):

Check these options in your report:

[image]

If the second one is turned on it can remove relationships from your model. You can turn them all off and adjust the relationships manually.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion.  All of these options are turned off, so my assumption is that it shouldn't try to add or delete anything.